# Why default is not used when I set not null contratint?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, notnull

I have table in postgresql database.

For given column I set default value, then I want it to be `NOT NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE "order" ALTER COLUMN last_bill_date SET DEFAULT '-Infinity';
ALTER TABLE "order" ALTER COLUMN last_bill_date SET NOT NULL;
```

But second statement fails:

```
ERROR:  column "last_bill_date" contains null values
```

**Why `DEFAULT` value is not used when `NOT NULL` is applied for this column?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)

> DEFAULT ***default_expr***
>
> (...)
>
> The default expression will be used in any insert operation that does not specify a value for the column. If there is no default for a column, then the default is null.

The altered default expression cannot modify rows already existing in the table, you should do it before setting the not null constraint:

```
update "order"
set last_bill_date = '-Infinity'
where last_bill_date is null
```

Comment: You shouldn't call it a constraint.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - opinions are divided [SQL DEFAULT Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp)

Comment: I see and am surprised. I'd refuse to call something a constraint if it does not constrain anything.

Comment: I agree that strict semantics indicate your point of view. I guess the term is quite popular because of its conciseness and ease of use.

Comment: @klin:  I read that postgresql (possibly 11?) can do lazy update for altered columns. And that lazy uses `default` value.

Comment: @EugenKonkov - AFAIK there is an improvement with not null default in pg11 but it concerns `alter table add column ...`